# Let $G$ be a graph which contains a complete subgraph $H$. Can $G$ be bipartite?

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a graph which contains a complete subgraph $H$.
>   Can $G$ be bipartite?

I found the answer to be NO.

In order for $G$ to be bipartite we must partition the vertex set of $G$ into two components $A,B$ such that no vertices in $A,B$ are adjacent among themselves.

If the graph $G$ contains $H$ as a complete subgraph its not possible to do so.

Is my logic correct?

Kindly help.

Comment: Yes, consider just a triangle. Two vertices will end up on the same set and thus no such graph exists

Comment: Well, a single edge is a complete graph on two vertices, to be precise. Not to mention a single vertex. You need to rule them out first and then the argument works.

Comment: If subgraph $H$ is $k_2$ or $k_1$ then $G$ can be bipartite. But for complete subgraph greater than 2. We have at least one odd cycle therefore $G$ can’t be bipartite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your argument is valid for $K_n$ with $n \ge 3$. For $K_1$ we can construct a graph with two $K_1$ components, which is bipartite. $K_2$ itself is already bipartite so argument becomes valid when we consider larger complete graphs. As an alternative way, you can prove the following argument by induction in order to prove your argument:

> For $n \ge 3$, $K_n$ has an odd cycle.

since a graph is bipartite if and only if it doesn't contain an odd cycle.

Comment: Here the Graph $G$ is not complete, it has a complete subgraph

Comment: Question asks "Can $G$ be bipartite" so first two are examples where it is bipartite. For others, if a subgraph contains an odd cycle, then original graph also does so..

Comment: Sorry,i dont get it

Comment: Which part you don't get it? First two being examples or subgraph containing odd cycle part?

Comment: subgraph containing ..

Comment: When we have an odd cycle as a subgraph of $G$, that cycle is odd in $G$ as well. Think about $C_3$ ($=K_3$). If a graph $G$ contains $K_3$, as a subgraph, adding vertices and edges to that subgraph cannot remove that odd cycle.